# Evitar que forms.ModelForm Django muestre información de la base de datos en el campo <select>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Tengo mi formulario en Django que hereda de forms.ModelForm. Este modelo tiene un atributo relacionado con ForeignKey que se muestra como <select> en el HTML, eso esta bien, el problema que tengo esta relacionado con que en el modelo tengo atributos por los cuales decido si la información es mostrada o no, resulta que el <select> muestra toda la información sea esta publica o no.

¿Cómo puedo manejar mi formulario para prevenir que la etiqueta <select> muestre datos que no debería?.

Una muestra del código:
Modelo:

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    product_to_send = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="sale_product", 
                       on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} - {self.product_to_send.name_product}"
```

Form:

```
class SaleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = ['product_to_send']
```

- *Aquí esta el 'product_to_send' del modelo que se desplega como <select> en el HTML*

¿Cómo hago para que la información que he definido que no se muestre basado en campos del modelo (como por ejemplo, un producto que ya venció, pues que no me lo muestre, pues esta ya no esta disponible) no se muestre?

Muchas gracias por leerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar el queryset de tu ModelForm para que te muestre solo objetos que no hayan vencido, suponiendo que tienes un campo booleano en el modelo Product para saber si ya esta vencido o no, iría de esta manera:

```
class SaleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SaleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Puedes aplicar un filtro diferente
        self.fields['product_to_send'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(vencido=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = ['product_to_send']
```

Ya solo tu eliges como filtrar los objetos que se muestran en el select.

Comment: Sí, esa es una manera de hacerlo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Sin embargo, estoy intentando filtrarlo por una función que tengo en la base de datos que retorna True o False y debería quedarme con el objeto que retorna False, el `self.fields['product_to_send']` debe recibir un QuerySet, y la verdad no he dado como hacer un filtro que me retorne un QuerySet (pues estos se retornan es por un atributo de la base de datos) y estoy intentando retornar el QuerySet por medio de una función que cree en la base de datos
`
def product_expired(self):
        return self.due_date < timezone.now()
`